# How to pass 2D array into array.prototype.map() with React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following 2D array `timeArray` in the state of my parent component in React. I am using it in the `render()` function as per follows:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div><Manager data={this.state.timeArray} /></div>
  );
}
```

In my `Manager` component's `render()` function, I then use the following:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.props.data.map((weekId, i) => (
        <Week key={i} weekData={weekId} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am expecting `weekData` when I pass it into `Week` to be an array, as `timeArray` from my parent component is a 2D array. However, when I use `console.log(this.props.weekData)` in `Week`'s `render()` function, I get `undefined`, not the actual data from the array. What is the best way to pass this in?

**EDIT:** Per request, here's most of the source:

**App**

```
// preceded by various imports
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      timeArray = []
    }
  }
  handleNewClick() {
    let tempWeek = this.getInput();
    let tempArr = this.state.timeArray.slice(0);
    console.log(tempArr); // logs []
    tempArr.push(tempWeek);
    console.log(tempArr); // logs [1, 1, 1, 1]
    this.setState({ timeArray: tempArr });
  }
  getInput() { // unimplemented, returning expected values for testing
    return [1, 1, 1, 1]
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Manager weeksData={this.state.timeArray} />
        <button onClick={this.handleNewClick.bind(this)}>
          Add Week
        </button
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

**Manager**

```
//various imports
class Manager extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.weeksData);
    // ^^ logs [1,1,1,1] for each button press, e.g.
    // 1 button press: [[1,1,1,1]]
    // 2 button presses: [[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1]] and so on
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.weeksData.map((weekId, i) => (
          <Week key={i} data={weekId} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Manager;
```

**Week**

```
// various imports
class Week extends React.Components {
  render() {
    let weekData = this.props.weekId;
    console.log(weekData); // logs undefined, which is not as expected
    render() { // unimplemented
      return <div></div>;
    }
  }
}
export default Week;
```

All code is used and rendered in a `Container` component, which is:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

class Container extends React.Components {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <App />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Container />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

Comment: Sorry for the rudimentary question, I'm still learning how to use ReactJS

Comment: I could not reproduce your problem. Can you post the rest of your code?

Comment: Can you add the code which initializes the `timeArray`?

Comment: @D-reaper done, see most recent edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you have a lot of typos in your code, I've fixed them in my solution below.

So the main issue here is that you are trying to access props that does not exist. When you pass `data` to your Week component (`data={weekId}`), the props `data` will exist in the Week component, and **NOT** `weekId` property. So if you access `this.props.data` instead of `this.props.weekId` you will get your data.

```js
// preceded by various imports
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      timeArray : []
    };
  }
  handleNewClick() {
    let tempWeek = this.getInput();
    let tempArr = this.state.timeArray.slice(0);
    console.log(tempArr); // logs []
    tempArr.push(tempWeek);
    console.log(tempArr); // logs [1, 1, 1, 1]
    this.setState({ timeArray: tempArr });
  }
  getInput() { // unimplemented, returning expected values for testing
    return [1, 1, 1, 1]
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Manager weeksData={this.state.timeArray} />
        <button onClick={this.handleNewClick.bind(this)}>
          Add Week
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// various imports
class Manager extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.weeksData.map((weekId, i) => (
          <Week key={i} data={weekId} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// various imports
class Week extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let weekData = this.props.weekId;
    console.log(weekData); // logs undefined, which is not as expected
    console.log(this.props.data); // logs the data as expected
    return <div>unimplemented component</div>;
    
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Wow, that was a really simple mistake, thanks for the assistance. And my apologies for being a novice, didn't mean to turn this into an extend debugging session.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in the code you haven't posted there's an error in how you're configuring your `timeArray` variable.  This works fine for me.

```
class ManagerContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { timeArray: [
    {id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}
    ]}
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div><Manager data={this.state.timeArray} /></div>
    );
  }
}

class Manager extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.data.map((week, i) => (
          <Week key={i} weekData={week} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}


class Week extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <p>week number: {this.props.weekData.id}</p>
    )
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<ManagerContainer />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

[and on jsbin](https://jsbin.com/samikaxiki/1/edit?js,console,output)

Comment: Does each element of `timeArray` need an `id`? The initialization is `timeArray: [];` in my constructor, but I then push arrays onto it using `let temp = [0,1,0]`, `let arr = this.state.timeArray.slice(0)` `arr.push(temp)`, and then `this.setState({ timeArray: arr })`, so `timeArray` is an array of arrays, but each element doesn't have an `id`. I can't reference them as `this.props.weekData.id` in the `Week` component.

Comment: I can add to my question if this isn't clear, as I didn't think this affected the error

Comment: The particulars about it shouldn't be important so long as you're handling the data correctly.  The code I posted runs like what I think you're expecting.  Compare your code to that and start changing it until something makes sense to you.